# EF 6 Code First, changing a Foreign Key Id with an Include on navigation property causes "A referential integrity constraint violation occurred" error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3 and have the scenario where I retrieve an entity with its navigation property (using Include()) and disconnect it from the context, change the foreign key Id then re-attach it to a new DbContext:

```
// Init the Db
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
   var theWarranty = new ProductWarranty { WarrantyName = "The Warranty" };
   var newWarranty = new ProductWarranty { WarrantyName = "New Warranty" };
   var brand = new ProductBrand { BrandName = "The Brand", DefaultWarranty = theWarranty };

   db.ProductBrands.Add(brand);
   db.ProductWarranties.Add(newWarranty);

   db.SaveChanges();
}

// Load the detached Brand
ProductBrand detachedBrand;
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
   detachedBrand = db.ProductBrands.AsNoTracking()
      .Include(b => b.DefaultWarranty)  // <<< If this line is removed the Attach works
      .First(x => x.Id == 1);
}

// Modify the Default Warranty Foreign Key
detachedBrand.DefaultWarranty = null;
detachedBrand.DefaultWarranty_Id = 2;

// Attempt to re-attach and save the changes
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
   var entity = db.Set<ProductBrand>().Attach(detachedBrand); // <<< This line throws the exception

   db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm getting:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of >'ProductWarranty.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property >value(s) of 'ProductBrand.DefaultWarranty_Id' on the other end.

However, if I do NOT use the Include() the attach works fine.

I do need the navigation property (DefaultWarranty) in the real-world scenario, but I don't see the difference in including the navigation in a detached entity vs not loading it in a detached entity. From my experience and reading it should be the case of setting the foreign key to the new value and set the navigation property to null.

I've read through Ladislav's blog on Foreign Key vs Independent properties http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/ but it doesn't quite deal with this scenario and from what I can tell I'm using foreign keys in this case.

What is happening and what is the correct way to deal with changing Foreign Keys with Included navigation properties like this scenario?

It's almost like EF hasn't "fully" detached the entity when the Include is used...which would seem odd as well.

Here is the simplified setup:

## Product Brand

```
public partial class ProductBrand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> DefaultWarranty_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductWarranty DefaultWarranty { get; set; }
}
```

## Product Brand Map

```
public class ProductBrandMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductBrand>
{
    public ProductBrandMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.BrandName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(40);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("ProductBrands");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.BrandName).HasColumnName("BrandName");
        this.Property(t => t.DefaultWarranty_Id).HasColumnName("DefaultWarranty_Id");

        // Relationships
        this.HasOptional(t => t.DefaultWarranty)
            .WithMany(t => t.ProductBrands)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DefaultWarranty_Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

## Product Warranty

```
public partial class ProductWarranty
{
    public ProductWarranty()
    {
        this.ProductBrands = new List<ProductBrand>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WarrantyName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductBrand> ProductBrands { get; set; }
}
```

## Product Warranty Map

```
public class ProductWarrantyMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductWarranty>
{
    public ProductWarrantyMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.WarrantyName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(40);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("ProductWarranties");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.WarrantyName).HasColumnName("WarrantyName");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it and it works without any exception!

Comment: @Alireza - Specifics of my dev and project are VS2013, .net 4.5.2. I ran the code again and I still get the error. I have also sent my project to a fellow developer and he is experiencing the same behaviour...and is equally perplex as I. Did you have specific steps you took to run the code ?

Comment: Would you send me your project?

Comment: @Alireza not sure how you tested it but I can reproduce this easily, just a simple model is enough. Looks like the detached entity still has some knowledge about the relationship (which was loaded by `Include`), this is fairly strange to me.

Comment: @Alireza - Download project files from http://expirebox.com/download/155d60675ebcdad9b18d23b4bbdd3113.html

Comment: detachedBrand.DefaultWarranty = null;
detachedBrand.DefaultWarranty_Id = 2; you try to attach this object, so the exception is pretty clear. of course you can't attach an object tree that does not match FK's. you want to be your navigation property to be null (FK=null), but FK=2 at the same time, this won't work. EDIT: oops :) of course in detached scenario your db structure won't be modified, still you try to attach a not-matching object tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `ProxyCreationEnabled` is enabled, even if the entities are not tracked by any context, they are somehow internally connected to each other. I mean, any changes in a FK is recorded carefully by the dynamic proxy entity to enforce referential integrity. So, simply turn off `ProxyCreationEnabled`:

```
public MyContext()
{
     this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```

But if you ask my opinion, I prefer to change entities when they are tracked and after modification I detach them.

Comment: Fantastic! Setting ProxyCreationEnabled = false when loading the entity did the trick! As for "I prefer to change entities when they are tracked and after modification I detach them" - The example is a simplified version of a WPF app that the user/UI layer modifies the detached entity then sends it back to the Application layer.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue when trying to assign a new foreign_key value.

I was doing the attach after having updated the foreign key on the core object this was an issue.

Instead, I now attach to the object, and then apply the change to the field.

```
public static bool ChangeForeignKeyAssocation(baseobject existing, int newFK, bool throwOnError = true) {
  try {
    using (var e = new Entities()) {
      e.table.Attach(existing);
      e.Entry(existing).State = EntityState.Modified;

      existing.related_table_id = newFK;

      int result = sbe.SaveChanges();
      return (result == 1);
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    //LogIt.E(ex);
    if (throwOnError) {
      throw ex;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```